# Salesforce add-on creation

Tags: integration

My team requested me to explore on Salesforce Add-On creation. I have gone through few links including (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/salesforce/info) but did not come to any conclusion. We have a cloud site for storing files and how to create an add-on to Salesforce for this.

Update:

I have followed these steps mentioned by @Mr.Frodo and completed the tutorial #2 from this [link](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/216/8/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf). Can we do the same without salesforce environment? like from visual studio code or some other tool?

Comment: by add-on you mean an app right?

Comment: @Mr.Frodo, yes (I guess, am not sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the basic standard steps one should follow to successfully create and launch a Salesforce app.

1. **Become a Salesforce Partner**: Your company should have salesforce partner account. You can sign-up for partner community from [here](https://partnersignup.salesforce.com/). Check [this link](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appinnovators/overview) for more detail about the partner program.
2. **Get Environment hub (Optional):** If you are a business partner then it will be automatically enabled for you otherwise you have to raise a support case. This tool is completely free.  [Environment hub](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Environment_Hub) will help you in creating and managing developer/test orgs. Orgs created from environment hub gets more licenses and greater limits.
3. **Security review:** When you are ready with your app, first thing would be to get the security review done. Follow steps described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review.htm) for more details.
4. **Publish on AppExchange:** [Appexchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/) is the Salesforce store of all apps. After passing the security review you need to follow [these steps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/appexchange_publish.htm#appexchange_publish) to publish your app on the appexchange.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Frodo. Let me check this out and update here.

Comment: I have followed these steps and completed the tutorial #2 from this [link](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/216/8/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf). Can we do the same without salesforce environment? like from visual studio code or some other tool?

Comment: No. You can use any IDE for writing the code but without salesforce env.you can't compile or execute the code.